# How disable the automount snap "disks"/drive?

Tags: snap, automount

I saw a lot of "disks" that comes from all thoses apps of snap in my Pc (Ubuntu 19.04), and I prefer disable the automount of Snap of thoses apps and mount the "disks/drives" when I launch a software.

I searched this on Google but I didn't find anything. Someone knows how do this? Sorry if the question is (probably) ridiculous.

Thanks!

Comment: How do these bother you? Regular apps also exist on your system in mounted folders after your system has started.

Comment: Are you talking about the loop filesystems? There are many questions here about those.

Comment: If they bother you only when using `df`, you can add something like this to your `~/.bash_aliases` file: `alias df="df -h | grep -vE '^(udev|tmpfs|/dev/loop)'"`

Comment: What I want is test if I can run faster Ubuntu when I start it. I saw Snap takes his time to load in the boot/systemd.